copilot cannot connect/authenticat with Github in VisualStudio, but it can within PyCharm
I was granted access to a Github-Copilot project to evaluate Copilot for my organization. I installed the GitHub extension within the VisualStudio code. However, there seems to be some failure in connecting or authenticating. I've spent two days on this, and nothing I've read has helped.
I tried to install the GitHub-Copilot extension within PyCharm on a whim, and that worked.
So, I feel that my account/authorization on Github is perhaps okay. I've uninstalled VS code and the copilot extension, but nothing helps. None of the results with similar issues within Google searches have helped. Below is the issue or something related to it. I can provide more info if needed.
2024-11-07 15:01:56.448 [info] [certificates] Removed 3 expired certificates
2024-11-07 15:03:56.157 [error] [auth] auth: HttpTimeoutError: Request to <https://api.github.com/copilot_internal/v2/token> timed out after 120000ms
    at /wmm_nbu/tfw/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.243.0/lib/src/network/helix.ts:95:19
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at cue.fetch (/wmm_nbu/tfw/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.243.0/lib/src/network/helix.ts:93:22)
    ... 5 lines matching cause stack trace ...
    at attemptAuthentication (/wmm_nbu/tfw/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.243.0/extension/src/auth.ts:58:9) {
  cause: AbortError: The operation was aborted.
      at fetch (/wmm_nbu/tfw/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.243.0/node_modules/@adobe/helix-fetch/src/fetch/index.js:96:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at cachingFetch (/wmm_nbu/tfw/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.243.0/node_modules/@adobe/helix-fetch/src/fetch/index.js:288:16)
      at cue.fetch (/wmm_nbu/tfw/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.243.0/lib/src/network/helix.ts:93:22)
      at fetchCopilotToken (/wmm_nbu/tfw/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.243.0/lib/src/auth/copilotToken.ts:196:16)
      at authFromGitHubToken (/wmm_nbu/tfw/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.243.0/lib/src/auth/copilotToken.ts:129:22)
      at auth (/wmm_nbu/tfw/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.243.0/extension/src/auth.ts:40:25)
      at authShowWarnings (/wmm_nbu/tfw/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.243.0/extension/src/auth.ts:131:25)
      at tae.getCopilotToken (/wmm_nbu/tfw/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.243.0/extension/src/auth.ts:174:33)
      at attemptAuthentication (/wmm_nbu/tfw/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.243.0/extension/src/auth.ts:58:9) {
    type: 'aborted',
    _name: 'AbortError'
  }
}
2024-11-07 15:03:56.158 [error] [auth] Request to <https://api.github.com/copilot_internal/v2/token> timed out after 120000ms
2024-11-07 15:04:28.745 [error] [default] Error sending telemetry FetchError: connect ETIMEDOUT 140.82.112.21:443
    at fetch (/wmm_nbu/tfw/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.243.0/node_modules/@adobe/helix-fetch/src/fetch/index.js:99:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at cachingFetch (/wmm_nbu/tfw/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.243.0/node_modules/@adobe/helix-fetch/src/fetch/index.js:288:16)
    at cue.fetch (/wmm_nbu/tfw/.vscode-server/extensions/github.copilot-1.243.0/lib/src/network/helix.ts:93:22) {
  type: 'system',
  _name: 'FetchError',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: -110,
  erroredSysCall: 'connect'
}

I am trying to get Copilot to connect and function within VisualStudio Code

You may have to check is there any self-signed certificate in the proxy/firewall and win-ca is installed? Otherwise try to install VS Code Insider to see if any error like that
